# Renaming GUID that has hypens to underscores in SQL Server

Tags: sql, rename, guid

SQL and trying for a solution. 
Case: 
Our System runs different Business process and outputs process result set into a new table called "Export_PROCESSSID". The ProcessID is GUID (XXX-XFG-EDRT ) but when the system creates the table it uses the ProcessID but rename it to (Export_XXX_XFG_EDRT). Hyphens are replaced with underscores and prefixed with "Export_".

Sofar:
First, I run a select statement to find the latest Process_ID in the table. Now I need to rename this GUID from this format "04ad20f5-3be6-481a-b341-d32f7702179f" to this "Export_04ad20f5_3be6_481a_b341_d32f7702179f".

Any ideas doing this t-sql with replace function or other methods? I am stuck here, any help will be appreciated. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what your context is, but this will transform `XXX-XFG-EDRT` into `Export_XXX_XFG_EDRT`:

```
'Export_' + REPLACE(ProcessID, '-', '_')
```

Comment: Many thanks. it worked great, i just need to change the double quote to single.

Comment: My mistake, fixed the example, and glad to have helped.

Answer (score 1):

For neatness, convert your GUID into a `varchar` first, then run `REPLACE` on it:

```
DECLARE @guid uniqueidentifier
SET @guid = newid()
SELECT 'Export_' + REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar(50), @guid), '-', '_')
```

Returns (at least, the last time I ran it):

```
Export_8D997451_F7B6_4EC5_9CFC_478B7084811A
```

Comment: Good point - it's not clear from the original question if the datatype is GUID.